# Question about calculation of expectation

Tags: probability-theory

When calculating the expectation with 
$f(x)=\begin{cases} x & 0 \leq x \leq 1 \\ 1/4 & x=2,3 \end{cases}$

I did so by, $E(X)=\int_{0}^1 x^{2} dx + \sum_{i=2}^3 if(i) $ .

Am I doing something wrong? Because when Im calculating the variance, I get a negative answer..

Comment: *How* did you calculate the variance?

Comment: $Var(X)=E(X^{2})-(E(X))^{2}$

Comment: You want to compute the expectation of a _random variable_, not of a function $f$.

Comment: Well, then what were the results of $EX^2$ and $(EX)^2$?

Comment: Yea my bad. Yes f is defined to be the density function of X.

Comment: $E(X^2)=3/2$, $E(X)^{2}=361/144$

Comment: This notation is certainly off, mixing a discrete distribution with a density.

Comment: Maybe you want to check your calculations of $E(X^2)$

Comment: I think I realized the issue now, when calculating the discrete part of E(X^2) it should be $\sum_2^3 i^{2} f(i)$ right?

Comment: Right. Unrelated: it's funny that you use the symbol of sum for a sum of two terms.

Comment: @fejz1234 : my opinion is that there is no _discrete part_ in the expectation of $X$ because $\lbrace 2 \rbrace$ or $\lbrace 3 \rbrace$ have measure $0$ for the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @zhoraster I prefer it that way ;)

Comment: @jibounet: There *is* a discrete part of the random variable. If one looks carefully at the definition of $f$, one can see that $f$ is *not* the density of a continuous random variable (simply because the integration of $f$ over ${\bf R}$ is not $1$.).

Comment: @Jack: Sorry, I still do not get it. Why is the integral of f not equal to 1 ? On which interval would you integrate f ?

Comment: @jibounet: well, how would you do the integral of $f$ over ${\bf R}$?

Comment: @Jack : For me $f$ is not defined on $\mathbb{R}$. It is only defined on $[0,1] \cup \lbrace 2,3 \rbrace$... In my opinion, the OP is trying to work out the expectation of a random variable $Z = X+Y$ where $X$ admits $x \mathbf{1}_{[0,1]}(x) dx$ as density  [where $dx$ denotes the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$], $Y$ admits $ \big( (1/4)\delta_{2}(m) + (1/4)\delta_{3}(m) \big) dC(m)$ [where $dC(m)$ denotes the counting measure on $\mathbb{N}$]. In that case, the PDF of $Z$ is not what is written in the OP.

Comment: It is nothing but a matter of notations. You said in a previous comment "my opinion is that there is no discrete part in the expectation of  $X$". Well, the $X$ you are referring to is the one in your decomposition $Z=X+Y$ (of course your $X$ has no discrete part). But the $X$ in OP means the $Z$ in your comment and thus has a discrete part.

Answer (score 1):

You have calculated $E(X)$ correctly (as it seems from the method) to get $\frac{19}{12}$.

The next step is to calculate $$E(X^2)=\int_0^1(x^2\times x)\mathrm dx+\sum_{i=2,3}\left(i^2\times\frac14\right)=\frac72$$

Then as you said, $Var(X)=E(X^2)-E(X)^2$, which should give a positive answer.